# Use save() method in Play! with inheritance (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I have my super abstract class :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class User {

    @Id
    public int id; 
    public String name; 
}
```

And two other classes extends User: 
 
**Customer**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer extends User{

    @Id
    public int id; 
    public String role; 

    public Customer(String role){
        super(); 
        this.role = role; 
    }
}
```

**Seller**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sellers")
public class Seller extends User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id; 
    public String role; // Seller

    public Seller(String role){
        super(); 
        this.role = role; 
    }
 }
```

I would like to be able to use the **save()** method in play, so I wrote this :

```
public static Result saveCustomer(){
        Customer customer = Form.form(Customer.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        customer.save();        
        return ok(); 
    }
```

But, **save()** is not defined.

What would be the way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually... to get the entityManager in **play 2.x** you hava a Helper.

```
JPA.em().persist(object);
```

you can see more information in this [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaJPA).

Comment: please... if it helped you mark it as correct so we close this :) @Mornor

Answer (score 0):

`save()` method is a part of `GenericModel` which belongs to `Play 1.x`. Since, you use `Play 2.x` you should use `JPA` object and `entityManager.persist()` method.